# Control Flash Applet From NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash

I have a Flash applet which runs in a web browser. Is there anyway that NodeJS could interact with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can interact with NodeJS only as far as you can manipulate the Flash applet. If the applet you want to interact with is already finished and doesn't include any code to interact with JavaScript - I think it's impossible.

If there is a way to edit Flash applet (you have the source files) there is a specific class interface that can enable you to communicate between Javascript (NodeJS/plugins) and Flash application (ActionScript) both way to some degree.

More info on this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

I never used this and I don't use Flash for several years now so I might be wrong or outdated a bit on this. Hope this helps.